# stack of coins, push function (C)

Tags: c, stack

I got a stack of coins, which are made this way:

```
#define MAX_PAIS 20

typedef int VALUE;

typedef struct {
    VALUE value;
    char country [MAX_PAIS];
} COIN;
```

and

```
#define MAXSTACK 100

typedef struct {
    int top;
    ELESTACK item [MAXSTACK];
} STACK;
```

to push a coin into the stack, I do:

```
STATUS push(STACK *stc, const ELESTACK *ele) {

    //stuff

    stc->top++;

    retorno = copyEleStack(stc->item[stc->top], ele);

   //stuff
}
```

the important thing is the copyElestack thing, my ide gives me an error, it says this function needs the first argument to be struct elestack * but is elestack... the mentioned function do that:

```
ELESTACK *copyEleStack(ELESTACK *dst, const ELESTACK *src) {

    int retorno;

    retorno = copyCoin(dst, src);

    if (retorno == ERROR) {
        return NULL;
    }


}
```

and copycoin:

```
STATUS copyCoin(COIN * pDest, const COIN * pOrigin) {

    pDest->value = pOrigin->value;

    strcpy(pDest->country, pOrigin->country);

    if (pDest->value != 0 && pDest->country != NULL) {
        return OK;
    }

    return ERROR;
```

I think this might be something related to the pointers, but I'm not seeing it right now, any help would be nice

Comment: What's the relation between `ELESTACK` and `COIN`?  If they are not the same, then your stack is not the size you think it is.

Comment: oh forget that part, elestack is coin type: typedef COIN ELESTACK;

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is telling you the right thing.  `copyEleStack` takes an `ELESTACK*`, but you are passing it an `ELESTACK` value.  Try `&stc->item[stc->top]`  or alternately `(stc->item+stc->top)`

Comment: also note that by doing `stc->top++` before the assignment, you never use the 0th element of your stack.

Comment: that kind of worked, but now he be warning me that I made an integer from a pointer without a cast lol -btw, i have top -1 as the top of a new stack, so I can access 0 position